# Reference for predefined exceptions in .NET

Tags: .net, exception

Does a reference exist with a catalog of predefined exceptions for the .NET framework along with examples of when is it appropriate to use each?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's possible to get a list of them while in Visual Studio: press `Ctl` + `Alt` + `E`

**EDIT**: I was able to find this site that has a pretty [comprehensive list of .NET Exceptions](http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/net-exceptions-all-of-them/) and a brief description of what causes them.

Comment: That is a nice way to get a list of what's available, but I'm interested in finding information about when it's appropriate to use each.  +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is MSDN. Start with System.Exception's class hierarchy and follow the trail.

[System.Exception hirarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx#familyToggle)

Comment: I just would love to get a simple list of all pre-defined exceptions. No such seems to be available for Aspnet Core.